# Possible MySQL error occurred during system upgrade

Tags: upgrade, mysql, system, error-handling

Run on terminal the command sudo apt-get upgrade. After a few seconds appears this:

```
Errors occurred while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.49-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help!

Comment: The actual error is not here -- it should be earlier, higher up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you paste all output from an apt-get update?

Maybe if you try this:

```
sudo rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql*
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: to @Carlos Gómez: /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.49-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)